# Please update to Xcode 7.3 or later to continue developing with your Apple ID

Tags: codenameone

I am now unable to generate iOS certificate and profile using the codename one certificate generation tool. I am getting the below msg from apple.
Please update to Xcode 7.3 or later to continue developing with your Apple ID

On checking my apple account, certificate is created but provisions profile is not.

Comment: The message I am getting is: Certificate generation failed. Failed to generate development provisioning profile. (UnexpectedResponse) ......Please update to Xcode 7.3 or later to continue developing with your Appl ID

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a regression in the wizard due to changes to Apples backend. We're working on resolving them and tracking it through this issue: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3571